# Extending existing Object to add additional JavaScript Prototype methods

Tags: javascript, prototype, extend

Let's say I have a function like the one below that creates a very simple micro-library:

```
var microLib = function(selector) {
    var el;
    var selectorEngine = function(selector)
    {
        var selector_value = selector.slice(1);
        return document.getElementById(selector_value);
    };

    el = selectorEngine(selector);

    Element.prototype.func_1 = function(){
        return 'first';
    };

    Element.prototype.func_2 = function(){
        return 'second';
    };

    return el;
};
window._$ = microLib;
```

This script will allow me to write code like this:

```
var elem = _$("#div_with_id");   //some element on my web page
console.log(elem.func_2());      //outputs 'second' in the console
```

So now, I'm looking for a way to extend `_$` in a supplementary piece of code to add additional `Element.prototype` methods, which will allow me to write:

```
console.log(elem.func_3());    //to output 'third' in the console
```

The reason I need to do this is because this *extension* needs to take place in another JavaScript file, otherwise I would I have just added another method and be done with it.

How can I do this?

Comment: That's very unclear, very bad practice (Extending Element without a really excellent reason is terrible), and very... useless??

Comment: Since you are already doing this horrendous practice of modifying `Element.prototype`, just add `func_3` in the same way. I don't understand where the problem is.

Comment: Since you are creating your own micro library, then why exactly do you need to modify Element.prototype?  Create methods on the prototype of the function such that these methods operate on the selected elements.  That way you can implement `_$(#div_with_id).func_3()` vs. `elem.func_3()`.

Comment: @Amit So what would you suggest is a better way of achieving the same effect? And what would be an excellent reason?

Comment: The "effect" isn't clear. What's the purpose? Show a real-world use case. And as for extending `Element.prototype`... Can't think of anything -> it's not something you do

Comment: @DRD I need to extend the object later on in the code.

Comment: Exactly, extend `_$` and not `Element`.

Comment: @DRD That's what I'm trying to do, but in a way that allows me to add a custom method to the DOM element the way `Element.prototype` does

Comment: See a more detailed example in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of the approach that I am suggesting: http://jsfiddle.net/rbxssmx8/.

JS:

```
var toArray = Function.prototype.call.bind(Array.prototype.slice);
var qAll = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document);

var _$ = (function() {
    function dom(selector) {
        if(!(this instanceof dom)) {
            return new dom(selector);
        }

        this.elements = toArray(qAll(selector));
    }    

    dom.prototype.iterate = function(func) {
        this.elements.forEach(func);
        return this;
    };

    dom.prototype.addClass = function() {
        var klasses = arguments;
        return this.iterate(function(element) {
            element.classList.add.apply(element.classList, klasses);
        });
    };

    dom.extend = function(name, func) {
        this.prototype[name] = func;    
    };

    dom.ready = function(func) {
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", func);    
    };

    return dom;
})();

_$.extend("removeClass", function() {
    var klasses = arguments;
    return this.iterate(function(element) {
        element.classList.remove.apply(element.classList, klasses);    
    });
});

_$("div").addClass("gray");
var $el = _$("div:last-of-type");
$el.removeClass("gray");
```

Comment: Thanks. Used some parts of it to fix my code. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

So I read this post on [What's wrong with extending the DOM](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/) and the alternative suggested by the author was to use Object Wrappers. A quick search on that led me to this post on SO: [Using object wrappers to extend the JavaScripts DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16279025/using-object-wrappers-to-extend-the-javascripts-dom)

Coupled with some insight from @DRD's answer, I updated my code:

```
(function() {

    var microLib = function (selector){
        return new Dom(selector);
    };

    function Dom(selector)
    {
        var selector_value = selector.slice(1);
        this.element = document.getElementById(selector_value);
    }

    Dom.prototype.func_1 = function(){
        return 'first';
    };

    Dom.prototype.func_2 = function(){
        return 'second';
    };

    microLib.extend = function(name, func){
        Dom.prototype[name] = func;
    };

    window._$ = microLib;

})();
```

And then whenever you want to extend and add another function, do this afterwards:

```
_$.extend('func_3', function(){ //this is inline with my earlier question
     return 'third';
});
```

Works like a charm! And definitely the *safer* option compared to extending `Element.prototype`.